# Overriding validation attribute from a base Model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i have a MVC controller called MyController with an action called MyAction. For other hand i have a Model called MyModel, and all this classes are in a project called Portal.Website (Asp.net MVC3 Application) that i use as a generic website and that store common functionalities for custom websites that i will add in the future.

For other hand i have another website project with a reference to Portal.Website project called Portal.Website.MyCustomWebsite.

This is the viewmodel MyModel.cs in the generic website part:

```
namespace Portal.Website
{
    public class MyModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage="The field Name is required.")]
        [Display("MyPropertyOriginal")]
        public virtual string Name{get;set;}
    }
}
```

This is the controller and action in the generic website part:

```
namespace Portal.Website
{
    public class MyController: Controller
    {
       [HttpPost]
       public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
       {
          if(Model.IsValid)
          ....
          //My issue: Im getting the error message in english, not the overridden one.

       }
    }
}
```

This is the viewmodel that i created in the custom part:

```
namespace Portal.Website.MyCustomWebsite
{
    public class MyModel: MyModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage="My error message in other language.")]
        [Display("MyPropertyOverriden")]
        public override string Name{get;set;}
    }
}
```

My problem:

I would like to override the ErrorMessage of the Required attribute. For this reason i created a new Model in my custom project. For other hand i would like to use the Controller/Action (MyController/MyAction) that is already defined in my common part.

Do you know if this is possible? Im only getting the issue with the Required attribute, but with the Display one its working perfect.

Thanks in advance.
Greets.
Jose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out this article that suggests two possible solutions :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/130586/Simplified-localization-for-DataAnnotations

I've found it was making more sense to re-create some DataAnnotation classes with my custom logic.

Answer (score 1):

MVC3 comes with better support for I18N (internationalisation) than it's predecessors - you can pass the `RequiredAttribute` the type of your resource class and the resource key and the error message will be displayed in whichever language is most appropriate:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MyResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ResourceKey")]
public override string Name { get; set; }
```